# MSSQL update from d1 to db 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have DB1 and DB 2
[image]

For some reasons my DB1 is my main DB and I want to update all values from the height of DB2 into the height column of DB1.

I DON NOT want to replace the table I just want to update the height where the ids match.

Comment: What's the question? How to specify the table names? Use their 3-part name for the remote table, `database.schema.tablename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem was, that I am not able to use different databases for the set and the from parameters of an update statement.

You need to join your from parameter with the secod DB to make this work

looks like this:

```
Update 
DB1.height 
Set
DB1.height = t2.height 
FROM
DB1 as t1
Inner join DB2.height t2 ON
t1.id= t2.id
```

Comment: What parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

You need `update` as follows

```
Update db1table d1
  Set d1.height = d2.height
Inner join db2table d2 on dq.id = d2.id
  And d1.height <> d2.height
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, if you are unpdating from a database to another the syntax should be like below :

```
UPDATE [ServerName].[DatabaseA].[Schema].MytableA 
SET Height = T2.Height
FROM [ServerName].[DatabaseA].[Schema].MyTableA T1
INNER JOIN [ServerName].[DatabaseB].[Schema].MytableB T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE MytableA (Id INT, [User] varchar(10), Age int, Height int)
> CREATE TABLE MytableB (Id INT, [User] varchar(10), Age int, Height int)
>
> INSERT INTO MytableB(Id,[User],Age, Height) VALUES (1, 'Norm', 22, 5)
> INSERT INTO MytableA(Id,[User],Age, Height) VALUES (1, 'Norm', 22, NULL)
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE MytableA 
> SET Height = T2.Height
> FROM MyTableA T1
> INNER JOIN MytableB T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM MytableA
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | User | Age | Height
> -: | :--- | --: | -----:
>  1 | Norm |  22 |      5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7eacfb5b0cdd9e4e778f650fd2cd860f)*

Comment: works great for different tables but not for different databases

Comment: @Taccoman just add the DB name and schema for each table.

Comment: getting the error "The multi-part identifier could not be bound"

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Management, if you use Database..(name of table) you can access different database from the one you are writing queries on.

```
update table1
set table1.height = table2.height
from DB1..table table1
inner join DB2..table table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```